# I want to read /reference the gcc compiler documentation. Using the --version command line option I get 'Ubuntu 5.4.0'

Tags: c, linux, gcc, version

> Yet https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/ doesn't have a 5.4 version?  Do I use 5.5 or 4.9 or another version's documentation? I am confused, I thought my system Linux mint 19 is current. Thanks for any clarification you can give. I am looking for a command line option to step through a program line by line for debugging.

Comment: The gcc website only keeps up the docs for the most recent release of each major compiler version. So the docs for 5.4 were replaced by the ones for 5.5.

Comment: @Shawn Thank you so very much.  I found instructions for upgrading to 6 or 9 although the most recent is 10. Still 5.4 is working fine.  I'll use the 5.5 documentation.